# How to match all zero valued cashflows?

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a function that needs to identify cashflows with zero value:

```
MatchQ[Cashflow[{{0,0},{1/2,0.`},{1,0.`},{3/2,0.`}}],Cashflow[{{_,c_/;Chop[c]==0}...}]]
```

The above is working for most cases but for some reason is failing here. What is wrong with this? Is there a better way to define the pattern for zero-valued cashflows?

Comment: `MatchQ[Cashflow[{{0, 0}, {1/2, 0.\`}, {1, 0.\`}, {3/2, 0.\`}}], Cashflow[{{_, 0 | 0.} ..}]]`

Answer (score 1):

another option is

```
MatchQ[Cashflow[{{0, 0}, {1/2, 0.`}, {1, 0.`}, {3/2, 0.`}}], Cashflow[{{_, _?PossibleZeroQ} ...}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think this is a good question. The issue can be seen here more closely

```
MatchQ[{{1/3, 0.`}, {1/3, 0.`}}, {{_, c_ /; Chop[c] == 0} ...}]
(*True*)
```

but, with changing one `0` to `0.`, it now gives `False`

```
MatchQ[{{1/3, 0.}, {1/3, 0}}, {{_, c_ /; Chop[c] == 0} ...}]
(*False*)
```

But both of the following give `True` !

```
MatchQ[{1/3, 0.`}, {_, c_ /; Chop[c] == 0}]
MatchQ[{1/3, 0}, {_, c_ /; Chop[c] == 0}]
```

So it seems the use of `Repeated` or `...` causes this type of test not to work on all, when it works on individuals.

I have not figured out why. So for now, avoid this kind of check, and use either `_?` or use the  alternative given by Bob in comment.